# how to remove text highlighting on drop down meny ul li and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

hi is ther e anyway of removing the highlights when you first click the meny (the grey bar). firefox seems to want to highlight all the text

http://www.jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/8

Comment: what browser? its fine on chrome

Comment: on firefox it highlights... chrome is fine ie8 is fine but firefox giving me trouble not sure what it is. dont really want to run a script to sort it.

Comment: have u tried loading up firebug to see if theres any errors?

Comment: yeah nothing really there that i can see that relates to the div it is contained in... .menu and .top_menu_menub

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be resolved if you remove the `height` and `width` lines from the following:

```
#menu li.sub {
    width: 200px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

This does not seem to produce any negative effects on Firefox or Chrome either, so it should be safe to remove it.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/9/)

As a side note, it looks like you have a lot more styling being applied than you need to (some parts being unnecessary or conflicting). I would recommend going through your CSS again and make sure everything looks the way you want it to. For example if you apply `background: red` to the above, you can see that the above `#menu li.sub` part seems to change dimensions when you hover over it, which is a bit unexpected.

Comment: thank you i will have a serious clean up, have noticed firefox does find a lot of errors the web tools but a lot of the time there is extra code to support other browsers.